# Order by date string in a concatenated SQL column

Tags: sql, sql-server

so I have a pretty tricky question that I haven't been able to figure out.
I have a query that displays the 2 following columns.

```
---------------------------                                      
3970131000-**2016-04-30** | CB90 

3970429000-**2016-06-30** | CB90

3970429000-**2016-03-31** | CB90

--------------------------------
```

I pretty much added two columns [Customer #] and DATE together.(=Lens)
My question is, how can I sort the result so it looks at the string DATE in the column and sorts it in DESC order.

This would be my desired output:

```
---------------------------    
3970429000-**2016-06-30** | CB90

3970131000-**2016-04-30** | CB90

3970429000-**2016-03-31** | CB90

--------------------------------
```

Thanks for the help! Here is my query for reference.

```
  select [Customer #] + '-' + cast(CAST(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,[Activation Date])+1,0)) AS date) as nvarchar) as Lens, 
  item AS PCAT
  FROM  [NasrWeb].[dbo].[LensBankInfo] 
     where [activation date]  
     between '2016-01-01' AND GETDATE()
     group by [Customer #] + '-' + cast(CAST(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,[Activation Date])+1,0)) AS date) as nvarchar), item
     ORDER BY LENS desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I am not sure why you have the group by as you are not aggregating any data. If you remove the group by, you can just order by the order by 
    CAST(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,[Activation Date])+1,0)) AS date) and use desc

```
select [Customer #] + '-' + cast(CAST(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,    [Activation Date])+1,0)) AS date) as nvarchar) as Lens, 
item AS PCAT
FROM  [NasrWeb].[dbo].[LensBankInfo] 
where [activation date]  
between '2016-01-01' AND GETDATE()
order by CAST(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,[Activation Date])+1,0)) AS date)
```

If you are actually aggregating and counting something but haven't included it in your example, then you can add the formula for the date portion into your group by since it doesn't impact anything and then order by it.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `right()`?

```
order by right(lens, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the date in that string is essentially the last day of the month of `[Activation Date]`, you could just sort on that column (after aggregation):

```
ORDER BY Max([Activation Date]) DESC
```